# Calculate function and sum for a combination of columns if past dates are available

Tags: python, pandas

I have this extract from a data (where the date range is between Juanary and February 2021)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'resp_id': [999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000],
                  'platform' : [35, 37, 38, 38, 43, 43, 44, 35, 37, 38, 38, 43, 43, 43, 44],
                  'date' : ['1/24/2021', '1/14/2021', '1/26/2021', '2/25/2021', '1/25/2021', '2/16/2021', '2/24/2021', '1/24/2021', '1/14/2021', '1/26/2021', '2/25/2021', '1/25/2021', '2/15/2021', '2/16/2021', '2/24/2021'],
                  't_a' : [3, 3.2, 0, 1, 2.3, 5.38, 0, 3, 3.2, 0, 1, 2.3, 1, 5.38, 0],
                  't_b' : [5, 3.2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1.4, 0, 2, 3.1, 1, 1.1, 0]})
```

I would need to find a way to measure `t_a / t_b` for each resp_id, platform and date. That is simple to do but I need to calculcate the sum of all `t_a / t_b` for each resp_id, platform from the date prior up to 28 prior.

For instance, resp = 1000 on platform = 43 and date =1/25/2021 will not considered becasue I don't have enough data (from yesterday up to the previous 28 days of data)

resp = 1000 on platform = 43 and date = '2/16/2021' will count all dates from '2/15/2021' up to 28 days back and will result in (2.3/3.1)

```
resp_id platform      date t_a  t_b t_a/t_b
1000          43 1/25/2021 2.3  3.1       0
1000          43 2/15/2021   1    1   0.742
1000          43 2/16/2021   1    1   1.742
```

Comment: Is this the complete output? How do you get 1/1 = 0.742? Also how do you want to handle the case where t_b = 0 (leading to infinite t_a/t_b)? C

Comment: @mozway that is a bit tricky and maybe not the best way to display, but 2.3/3.1 = 0.742 becasue for the resp = 1000, platform= 43 and date = 2/15/2021 the only previous date available (within 28 days) is that where t_a = 2.3  and t_b = 3.1.